# Is the exponential distribution subexponential?

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution

This might be a silly question at first nut nonetheless a valid one.

Is the exponential distribution with parameter $\theta$ actually a subexponential distribution. For an exponential pdf

$$ f_X(x) = \theta e^{-\theta x} $$
They key is to prove that

$$ E\left[ e^{s\left( X-\mu \right)} \right] =\frac{\theta e^{-s/\theta}}{\theta -s} \leq e^{\frac{\nu^2 s^2}{2}} $$

for some $\nu$ and $|s|< \theta$ where the last inequality followes from the MGF of the exponential distribution.

I found a reference [1] on this topic proving something similar but could not prove it myself, which is

$$ \frac{e^{-s}}{\sqrt{1-2s}} \leq e^{2s^2} $$
for $|s| \leq 1/4$.

Thanks.

[1] [https://www.google.jo/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjCvaT14bfTAhVJFMAKHfzjCJYQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.berkeley.edu%2F~mjwain%2Fstat210b%2FChap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGUy7T9ZjIcnFVnwS0Pg5dzrRVXJQ&sig2=hMT1V_UJDjplx0L3irqLig]

Comment: Since the left hand side $\theta e^{-s/\theta} / (\theta-s)$ blows up as $s\to\theta$, there cannot possibly exist any finite upper bound for $|s|\lt\theta$.

Comment: $\frac{e^{-s}}{\sqrt{1-2s}} \leq e^{2s^2}$ is equivalent to $|1-2s|\gt e^{-2s-4s^2}$ which is indeed true for  $|s| \leq 1/4$

Comment: Thanks. Might I also ask about how to verify your last statement $|1-2s|$ >e^{-2s-4s^2}. Apologies if this question is too basic.

Comment: @SamiAlDalahmah I've done my best here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474365/show-that-an-exponential-rv-is-sub-exponential